# org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to consume a webservice using. My client runs as a JSP pages hosted on Tomcat. While trying to consume the service I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unexpected error: null
```

I know that this problem is on the server side. I am using a RPC style SOAP request. I am new to JAVA and web services so I need a way to get to the faulty variable. How can I resolve this?

---

```
type Exception report

message Unexpected error: null

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

Unexpected error: null
    org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.Ouxxxxxxx._xxxx.OutagexxxxxxxStub.newOutageRequest(OxxxxxxxxxxxngStub.java:1986)
    com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.Outxxxxxxxrvice._xxxx.OutxxxxxxxxxxiceProxy.newOutageRequest(Oxxxxxxxxy.java:158)
    com.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.doPost(SubmxxxxID.java:178)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add activation.jar from the JAF (Java Activation Framework) in your classpath.

Comment: Can you give me some details as to how this will solve my issue. Do I add this to my classpath for the client or should I ask that this be added to the server?

Comment: copy the activation.jar file into the axis/WEB-INF/lib directory of your J2EE server

Comment: I added it to my eclipse project  WEB-INF/lib folder but that did not work

Comment: add it in your tomcat installation. lib/ext folder and restart server.

Comment: Appreciate your patience on this but that did not work. I put the activation.jar file in the  C:\Tomcat\Tomcat7.0\lib folder restarted the service and no change. I got the same exact error

Comment: "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request." on the error  somehow tells me the null exception is not being thrown by my code.